# vivo.sx video link extractor in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, video

I have written a Programm which loads all the series from bs.to and now I have the Problem that I cant get the vivo.sx (for example) direct video Links. The Links are visible in the Inspect Element section from right clicking on the Page after starting the Video. In the html code the link is in the second Javascript codeblock i think. Does anyone of you have an Idea on how to get the direct video link?
I am programming in c#, Windows Forms.
[For example the direct link for that video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Yd6.jpg)
https://vivo.sx/dcd747a9af

Kind regards

Andreas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I dont know what you exactly mean. I don't have any code snippets untill now. I don't have any idea of how to do this.